# Can only mount with gparted

Tags: mount, gparted

I have the following /etc/fstab entry which fails to execute at system boot/startup:

```
/dev/sdb1   /media/ssd256   ext4    rw,user,exec,umask=000 0 0
```

Doing

```
sudo mount -a
```

yields:

```
mount: /media/ssd256: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

However, if I sudo gparted and mount via its UI, then the device is mounted.
I am not sure how to fix this issue.

EDIT:
I changed the options to use `defaults` instead of `rw,user,exec,umask=000`, now `sudo mount -a` also works.
The question now is: what is wrong with my initial options?

Comment: Does gparted actually show an ext4 filesystem type for this device? 
What output for fsck command on /dev/sdb1? 
What if you replace options rw,user,exec,umask=000 with just "defaults"?

Comment: Did you `fsck /dev/sdb1` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why...

`dmesg | tail` will show:

```
EXT4-fs (dm-4): Unrecognized mount option "umask=000" or missing value
```

Indeed, the *umask* option is not part of the accepted options for the *ext4* file system : see `man mount`.